# Making nitrogen over Yaws from github.com

Tags: github, makefile, rel, yaws, nitrogen

I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS with all softwares upgraded according to the software manager utility

I am trying to create a nitrogen application over yaws from the [nitrogenproject site](http://nitrogenproject.com)   using

```
git clone https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen
make rel_yaws
```

During the compilation stage i get the following errors

```
==> yaws (compile)

=ERROR REPORT==== 5-Jan-2014::17:02:26 ===
Cannot read "/home/good/yaws_nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/lib/yaws/src/../ebin/../priv/charset.def": "no such file or directory"
--- Installing local config file at /home/good/yaws_nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/lib/yaws/etc/yaws/yaws.conf
Compiled src/yaws_shaper.erl
```

Then compilation continues until it terminates prematurely with this error

```
Compiling /home/good/yaws_nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/lib/yaws/c_src/epam.c
/home/good/yaws_nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/lib/yaws/c_src/epam.c:2:22: fatal error: pam_appl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
ERROR: compile failed while processing /home/good/yaws_nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen/lib/yaws: rebar_abort
make[3]: *** [compile] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/good/yaws_nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/good/yaws_nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen'
Generating a default cookie in /etc/vm.args
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/good/yaws_nitrogen/nitrogen/rel/nitrogen'
```

What can i do?
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 4):

I followed the same steps as you and built successfully on Ubuntu 12.04, no problem. The first error during the Yaws compile is harmless — you can just ignore it. The second problem is caused by the fact that you're missing the libpam0g-dev package. Try this step before attempting to rebuild Nitrogen:

```
sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev
```

If you still have trouble, you might also consider running:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep yaws
```

to ensure you have all the necessary packages installed.